# Can't delete english UK language in itunesconnect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-app

I am trying to send an application to the review in itunesconnect.

I have noticed that my primary language is English UK (don't know why). I would like to change it to English US and delete English UK.

I managed to change the primary language to English US, but it is impossible to delete English UK. I am deleting it, saving and it looks okay until I refresh the page. The UK language is still there. This problem do not exist with other language (I can add them and remove without a problem). What may cause this issue?

Comment: Do you have a storyboard or anything else that is localised in UK language?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select English UK from the top right corner and from there you will be able to remove it, like this:

[image]

If you have selected an other language, it wont let you remove that language.